# factory runner does not support sending transactions

Tags: blockchain, solidity, hardhat, hyperledger-besu

I'm trying to make a blockchain network using hyperledger besu and hardhat to upload a smart contract but I'm getting this error, I would like to use this contract on a private ibft 2.0 network:

```
Error: factory runner does not support sending transactions (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.10.0)
    at makeError  {
  code: 'UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION',
  operation: 'sendTransaction',
  shortMessage: 'factory runner does not support sending transactions'
}
```

deploy.js:

```
// We require the Hardhat Runtime Environment explicitly here. This is optional
// but useful for running the script in a standalone fashion through `node <script>`.
//
// You can also run a script with `npx hardhat run <script>`. If you do that, Hardhat
// will compile your contracts, add the Hardhat Runtime Environment's members to the
// global scope, and execute the script.
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const token = await hre.ethers.deployContract("FakeNewsValidator");
  console.log("Token address:", await token.getAddress());
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

hardhat.config.js:

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  // in built test network to use when developing contracts
  hardhat: {
    chainId: 1337
  },
  quickstart: {
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545",
    chainId: 1337,
    // test accounts only, all good ;)
    accounts: [
      "8f2a55949038a9610f50fb23b5883af3b4ecb3c3bb792cbcefbd1542c692be63",
      "c87509a1c067bbde78beb793e6fa76530b6382a4c0241e5e4a9ec0a0f44dc0d3",
      "ae6ae8e5ccbfb04590405997ee2d52d2b330726137b875053c36d94e974d162f"
    ],
    gas: 1048576,
    gasPrice: 0
  },  
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.19",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  },
  paths: {
    sources: "./contracts",
    tests: "./test",
    cache: "./cache",
    artifacts: "./artifacts"
  },
  mocha: {
    timeout: 40000
  }
};
```

contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

contract FakeNewsValidator {
    address public owner; // Variável que armazena o endereço do proprietário do contrato

    // Construtor do contrato, executado apenas uma vez durante a implantação
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender; // Define o criador do contrato como o proprietário
    }

    // Função pseudo-aleatória para determinar verdadeiro ou falso
    function getRandomBool(uint256 _newsId) private view returns (bool) {
        uint256 random = uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, block.prevrandao, _newsId)));
        return random % 2 == 0;
    }

    // Função para obter detalhes de uma notícia existente com base no ID
    function getNewsItem(uint256 _newsId) external view returns (bool) {
        return getRandomBool(_newsId);
    }
}
```

I wanted to try deploying the contacto again because every time I make the request through Postman I receive this error:

```
Erro ao acessar o contrato: AbiError: Parameter decoding error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
    at decodeParametersWith 
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  innerError: undefined,
  code: 205,
  props: {
    internalErr: AbiError: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
        at decodeParametersWith {
      innerError: undefined,
      code: 205,
      props: {}
    }
  }
}
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const { Web3 } = require('web3');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

console.log('Inicializando Web3 com HTTP Provider.');
const web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545'); // URL do seu nó Besu

// Carregar o contrato inteligente
console.log('Carregando ABI e endereço do contrato.');
const contractABI = [
  {
    "inputs": [],
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "constructor"
  },
  {
    "inputs": [
      {
        "internalType": "uint256",
        "name": "_newsId",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "name": "getNewsItem",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "internalType": "bool",
        "name": "",
        "type": "bool"
      }
    ],
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "owner",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "internalType": "address",
        "name": "",
        "type": "address"
      }
    ],
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
  }
]
const contractAddress = '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3'; // Coloque o endereço do seu contrato aqui

// Crie uma instância do contrato
console.log('Criando instância do contrato.');
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);

app.get('/check-news/:newsId', async (req, res) => {
  const { newsId } = req.params;
  console.log(`Recebido newsId: ${newsId}`);

  // Validar o parâmetro de entrada
  if (!newsId || isNaN(newsId)) {
      console.error('ID da notícia inválido:', newsId);
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'ID da notícia inválido.' });
  }

  try {
    console.log(`Buscando informações para o ID da notícia: ${newsId}`);
    console.log(`Buscando informações para o ID da notícia: ${newsId}`);
    const result = await contract.methods.getNewsItem(newsId).call();
    
    // Decodificar manualmente os valores retornados
    const newsItem = {
        sender: result[0],
        news: result[1],
        isFake: result[2]
    };

    console.log('Informações da notícia recebidas:', newsItem);
    res.json({ newsItem });
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Erro ao acessar o contrato:', error);
      console.error('Detalhes do erro:', error.reason, error.receipt);
      if (error.message.includes('revert')) {
          res.status(404).json({ error: 'ID da notícia não encontrado.' });
      } else {
          res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro ao acessar o contrato.' });
      }
  }
});


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor rodando na porta ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it for sure, but you might need a signer when you instantiate a contract. I encountered the same issue, but I resolved it by using ether.js. Here is my code before the unresolved issue:

```
async function safeMint(address,value){
await window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider( window.ethereum);

const contract =  new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, erc20, provider);
if (!value){
    value="10000000000";
}

let callback = await contract.safeMint(address,value)
return callback;
```

}

fixed code:

```
async function safeMint(address,value){
await window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider( window.ethereum);
const signer = await provider.getSigner();
const contract =  new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, erc20, signer);
if (!value){
    value="10000000000";
}

let callback = await contract.safeMint(address,value)
return callback;
```

}